# Magento 2: Why do I see an extra IMG tag beside the actual IMG intended for logo on the home screen?

Tags: magento2.3, frontend, phtml, frontend-error, logo

as seen in the image below, my Magento site displays an IMG tag before the IMG tag meant for displaying logo on the homepage. Please tell me how to eliminate the first unwanted IMG tag logo-white.svg. thanks.

[image]

Comment: try turning on the template path hints

Comment: Marius, thanks a lot. I found this file adding the unwanted IMG tag in the header. /public_html/vendor/swissup/module-theme-editor/view/frontend/templates/header/logo-alt.phtml. This is coming from our own theme which we customized.

Comment: Do you I think I should override this file by deleting the line of code that puts this logo before the actual one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out `= $block->getChildHtml('logo-alt')` in `logo.phtml` file in the custom module so that only the intended logo appears not together with the default logo provided by the theme.

Thanks...